# Trouble running main class with java command when class files are in a bin subdirectory

Tags: java, compilation

My file structure is:

```
dbscan/
      .vscode/
             launch.json
             settings.json
      bin/
         taxidbscan/
                   Cluster.class
                   DBScan.class
                   GPScoord.class
                   OutputReader.class
                   OutputRecord.class
                   TaxiClusters.class
                   TaxiReader.class
                   TaxiWriter.class
                   TripRecord$Label.class
                   TripRecord.class
      src/
         taxidbscan/
                   Cluster.java
                   DBScan.java
                   GPScoord.java
                   OutputReader.java
                   OutputRecord.java
                   TaxiClusters.java
                   TaxiReader.java
                   TaxiWriter.java
                   TripRecord.java
```

This is a school assignment so my TA need to be able to run this package from command line. My goal here is to simply compile to the bin folder to keep things organized and the class files separate.

I navigate to my root directory and I compile using this to get all the files:

```
dbscan> javac -d bin/ src/taxidbscan/*.java
```

I'm getting the same error when running my main class regardless of what I try. I think I've tried every permutation of this command:

```
dbscan> java -cp bin src/taxidbscan/TaxiClusters
```

```
Error: Could not find or load main class taxidbscan.TaxiClusters.java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: taxidbscan.TaxiClusters.java
```

If it comes to it and I have no solutions, I will compile and run everything from the src folder

In hindsight, I should have used an IDE for this project, not vscode, but it's too late for that now. Vscode java extension does successfully compile and run everything, its just command line that's the worst.

Comment: The -d flag is for specifying where to place the generated files. So `javac -d bin/src/taxidbscan/*.java` is not what you want.

Comment: I forgot to put a space. It all compiles to the bin folder as shown in the file structure. The issue I'm having is running it from that folder.

Comment: You need to run the class file that gets generated, not the java source file. Try running `java TaxiClusters` from /bin/taxidbscan

Comment: Yeah you're right about that, was a silly typo. I got it to run with: `java -cp bin taxidbscan.TaxiClusters `

Comment: Awesome. Posting this as an answer for visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Need to run the generated class file, not the source file. `java -cp bin taxidbscan.TaxiClusters`